# Finding Where Put Option Equals K-S, using the Black-Sholes, throws Exceptions. Why?

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, computational-finance

I am trying to find the value of the **`S`** where a Put option equals `K-S` in Python, where `K` is the strike price of the option and `S` is the underlying strike price. Also, in the function call of the Black-Sholes, `sigma` is the volatility, `delta` is the dividends paid, `T` is the time to expiration, `r` is the risk-free rate of interest.

I am testing it with K=75, r=0.05, T=1/12, sigma =0.35.

Furthermore, I know that my pricing for the Black-Sholes works as I have used it in a previous project of mine, it is possible that the modified versions of a syntax error.

I have tried using **`scipy.optimize`**, but I keep getting errors.

Is there another method, I should use? 
If so, how?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as ss
import time
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import datetime
import scipy.optimize

from scipy.optimize import newton


# initial stock price
type = 'C'

def d1(S0, K, r, sigma, T, delta):
    return (np.log(float(S0) / K) + (r - delta + sigma ** 2 / 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))


def d2(S0, K, r, sigma, T,delta):
    return (d1(S0, K, r, sigma, T,delta)-sigma * np.sqrt(T))


def blackScholes(type, S0, K, r, sigma, T, delta):
    if type == "C":
        return S0 * np.exp(-delta * T)* ss.norm.cdf(d1(S0, K, r, sigma, T, delta)) - K * np.exp(-r * T) * ss.norm.cdf(d2(S0, K, r, sigma, T, delta))
    else:
        return K * np.exp(-r * T) * ss.norm.cdf(-d2(S0, K, r, sigma, T, delta)) - S0 * ss.norm.cdf(-d1(S0, K, r, sigma, T, delta))

# args is args = (type,K,r,sigma,T,delta)
# Modifying Black-Sholes function arguments for multivariate optimization
def d1Modified(S, args):

        type = args[0]
        K = args[1]
        r = args[2]
        sigma = args[3]
        T = args[4]
        delta = args[5]
        return (np.log(float(S) / K) + (r - delta + sigma ** 2 / 2) * T) / (sigma * np.sqrt(T))

def d2Modified(S, args):
    type = args[0]
    K = args[1]
    r = args[2]
    sigma = args[3]
    T = args[4]
    delta = args[5]
    return (d1Modified(S,args) - sigma * np.sqrt(T))

def blackScholesModified(S, args):
    type = args[0]
    print("print args")
    print(args)
    K = args[1]
    r = args[2]
    sigma = args[3]
    T = args[4]
    delta = args[5]
    if type == "C":
        return S * np.exp(-delta * T) * ss.norm.cdf(d1Modified(S, args)) - K * np.exp(
            -r * T) * ss.norm.cdf(d2Modified(S,args))
    else:
        return K * np.exp(-r * T) * ss.norm.cdf(-d2Modified(S, args)) - S * ss.norm.cdf(
               -d1Modified(S,args))


print("Pricing a European Put Option")

p = "P"

#Note: at is the tuple with the inputs into the black-sholes equation
# Where p is a string indicating a put option, K is the strike price
# r is the risk free rate of interest, sigma is volatility, T is time to
# expiration and delta is dividends
ar = (p,K,r,sigma,T,delta)


putOptionPriceList = []
for i in range(1,74):
    stockPriceList.append(i)

for x in stockPriceList:
    price = blackScholes("P",x,K,r,sigma,T,delta)
    print(price)
    putOptionPriceList.append(price)



# Constraints for multivariate optimization where price = K-S
def con(S,ar):
    k= 75
    return blackScholesModified(S, ar) -(k-S)


cons = {'type':'eq', 'fun': con(S,ar)}


sPrice = scipy.optimize.minimize(blackScholesModified, 0.1, args=ar, constraints=cons)

print("Value sought")
print(sPrice)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    sPrice = scipy.optimize.minimize(blackScholesModified, 0.1, args=ar, constraints=cons)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 458, in minimize
    constraints, callback=callback, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 311, in _minimize_slsqp
    meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['eq']]))
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 311, in <listcomp>
    meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['eq']]))
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Comment: Being new to StackOverflow, there might be a value for you to note, the edit(s) history is being stored & re-readable *( forever )*, so rather be cautious and carefull **not to post any sensitive data** ( passwords, PIN(s), access-token(s), etc. ) as still being visible in http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43301278/revisions Anyway, enjoy this great Community of Knowledge and feel free to become a next actively contributing Member.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be to carefully follow the 0.18 specified calling interface:

```
   cons = { 'type': 'eq',
            'fun':   con,       # con( S, ar ) here'd yield float64, not callable
            'args':  ( S, ar )  #    ( ^__^__)_ passed to a fun == con()-callable
             }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I change that I get the following error:

Comment: `File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py", line 311, in <listcomp>
    meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args'])) for c in cons['eq']]))
TypeError: con() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: If you read the `slsqp.py` + decode a bit more carefully the calling-interface, which is using indirectly assembled parameters to meet the spec, the user-provided Constraint-function (**`con(...)`**) shall have a different calling-interface, than was defined above. As seen from the `slsqp.py` source, **`scipy.optimize.minimize()`** expects the Constraint-function to always receive **`x`**, as it's first parameter (auto-delivered from `scipy` internalities), next, iterated, whatever amount of parameters, def'd indirectly, via a single "packing" tuple **`cons['args']`** so `def con( x, S, ar):`